# Legacy IE hack: label not focusing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, label

I am working with legacy code and I've stumbled across this piece of art:

```
//IE Hacks
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    $("label").live('click', function() {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).click().click().click();
    });
}
// End IE Hacks
```

I was told this was written, because labels were not always working in IE and this trick fixed it. Also it didn't work with two `.click()` calls, but the all three were needed.

The jQuery version used is `1.4.2`.

I want to refactor this to use feature detection and a more elegant solution.

I looked on Google for label problems in IE and stumbled only on problems with hidden inputs.

Does anyone know what could be the problem which this code solves?

Is there a more elegant solution?

**UPDATE**:

Do you think there is not a problem which this code could have possibly solved and I should just remove it?

**UPDATE 2**:

I have found a problem with labels on the site. Here is a piece of HTML:

```
<div class="remember-me">
    <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="1" class="checkbox-input" rel="remember">
    <label class="label-remember" for="remember">Keep me logged in</label>
</div>
```

This HTML code is inserted into the page with Ajax so it might be related to the problem described from kevmc.

In Internet Explorer 7 clicking the label does not check the checkbox. Instead it focuses the label (with a thin dotted border).

Comment: You’re asking for an alternative solution to a problem when you don’t even know whether it really exists …?

Comment: @CBroe I am not even sure what is the original problem. My current problem is this code which I don't know whether it is working and I don't know how to rewrite it better.

Comment: Do you _have_ any problems in your page with older IEs?

Comment: I've been working with IE for a very long time, and I've never known of any problems with `<label>` for which that code could possibly be a solution. The main IE `<label>` problem was that you *had to* use the "for" attribute; wrapping an `<input>` in a label would not implicitly associate them.

Comment: @Pointy Might be the "problem" that you can't trigger anything hidden by clicking a label?

Comment: @Alex I've researched those problems and I can't find a way in which this code could resolve it.

Comment: It's crazy to use .click().click().click() and calling it worked great !!! First please confirm if your code is really working

Comment: @Alex - ah yes, that's a possibility (though one ".click()" would surely be enough :-) - I have gotten into the habit of hiding checkbox and radio inputs by making them "position: absolute" and "left: -10000px".  That leaves them "visible" as far as IE is concerned, but they're not actually in view.

Comment: @CBroe @Alex @hop I have updated the question. `Do you think there is not a problem which this code could have possibly solved and I should just remove it?`

Comment: @Pointy Yeah that's one of handling that I've used as well.

Comment: I experimented with IE7 and IE9. In IE9 you had to double click the label to check the checkbox. In IE7 the label got focused and the checkbox was not checked. Removing the ugly hack entirely fixed it in all versions. I am not sure if I should accept an answer here, write my own answer or just the update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE < 8 equates "name" attributes with "id"](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html), so clicking the label is probably sending focus to the hidden input since it appears earlier in the DOM and this would explain why the checkbox is not responding to the label clicks in IE7.

While I'm not sure how triggering the click event three times solves this, the most elegant solution would be to remove the `hidden` input. However, the `hidden` input is probably there to *always* send a value when the form is submitted, unlike checkboxes, which are only passed if they are successful (checked).

To solve the label focus issue, we should change the markup to take advantage of the browsers' default behavior, which is to send clicks on labels to their corresponding form element (by "id"). So we'll keep the `hidden` input to send the same parameters to the backend, but change the `id` of the checkbox and update the `for` attribute of the `label` to match:

```
<div class="remember-me">
  <input type="hidden" id="remember" name="remember" value="0">  <!-- added @id -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="rememberCB" class="checkbox-input"> <!-- changed @id, removed @name -->
  <label class="label-remember" for="rememberCB">Keep me logged in</label> <!-- changed @for -->
</div>
```

*Note:* we removed the `name` attribute from the checkbox input, since we don't want to include its value in the form submission. Instead, we'll change the `script` to update the value of the hidden input when the checkbox changes:

```
$('#rememberCB').live('change', function() {
  $('#remember').val( $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0' );
});
```

This way, the backend should receive the same input parameters when the form is submitted and the label(s) will send focus to the correct target.

See this in action here: http://jsbin.com/obujoc/6/edit

Comment: Your remarks are useful, but totally unrelated to the problem. Also the backend of this system is so full strange code I don't want to refactor the things responsible for form processing which are form buildings, ORM extensions and spaghetti controllers.

Comment: Do you understand that the hidden input has nothing to do with the problem? My problem with the frontend is the same if I didn't have it. Also I don't want to change the value of the hidden input with JS. The problem which everyone else got almost right is that clicking the label in old IE does not check the checkbox and this ugly hack I have in the legacy code.

Comment: Actually, the hidden input and the backend's dependence on it are precisely the answer to your question of "what could be the problem which this code solves." The hidden input is there to send a key/value pair to the backend with every submission (because the checkbox only sends them when checked). The hidden input shares the same "name" as the checkbox, which in IE < 8 is equivalent to an "id". This is why the triple-click is necessary - to overcome the confusion of multiple "id"s. The "more elegant solution" is to change the checkbox's "name" and "id" and update the input accordingly.

Comment: Also, since IE < 8 equates "name" with "id" for form elements, clicking the label is probably sending focus to the hidden element since it appears earlier in the DOM. My answer addresses this by changing the "name" and "id" of the checkbox and changing the "for" of the label to match.

Comment: I was completely unaware of that behavior of IE < 8 and didn't do any tests for it either. If you consider updating your answer with this and clear things up I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Also I'm sorry I've misunderstood you at first, but this wasn't visible from your answer unless a person did know about this bug/behavior.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to mention old IE's "name" and "id" confusion and I kept it on-topic. It's much better now and shorter, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

When a label/input pair is added to the DOM after page load older versions of IE (I haven't tested it since IE8) did not seem to recognize the binding between the for and id attributes. As for an elegant test I don't know of one

Comment: My issue was with radio buttons and since the click method was unreliable I ended up manually setting the checked attribute

Answer (score 0):

hi why you are using click event ? just need to set focus ! like this :

```
    //IE Hacks
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    $("label").live('click', function() {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).focus();
    });
}
// End IE Hacks
```

Comment: It should focus `input[type=text]`, but it should check `input[type=radio]` and `input[type=checkbox]`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think the hack can be used in `<!--[if IE]> <![endif]-->` tag?

Let me show you an example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    $("label").live('click', function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).focus();
});
<![endif]-->
```

Not sure what your code does, but if you use it as i show you with a simpler code it will work.

Comment: That's nice and I can easily use it for a specific version of IE as well, but it does not solve my problem at all.